# Is $\hbar, c, e$ truly independent?

Tags: units, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

Considering the constants: $\hbar, c, e$. Basically people considering them as very independent constant. However, if you think about it, $\hbar$ was initially introduced during $E=\hbar \nu$, thus connected to Lorentz/Maxwell $c$ and electron orbits which carries $e$.

An easy way to see such connection was through [Fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) (though it's changing).

Thus is $\hbar, c, e$ truly independent? or were they formalized as manifestly dimension?

Comment: What is your definition for such dimensionful constants to be "truely independent"?

Comment: Most physicists do not accept that the fine structure constant is changing. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Is_the_fine-structure_constant_actually_constant?), which says “So far, most experimental data is consistent with α being constant.”

Comment: *or were they formalized as manifestly dimension*: could you rephrase this sentence? I couldn't figure out what you meant.

Answer (score 3):

> $\hbar$ was initially introduced during $E=\hbar\nu,$ thus connected to Lorentz/Maxwell $c$ and electron orbits which carries $e$.

The historical context in which $\hbar$ was introduced has nothing to do with its actual significance in physics. In current physics, Planck’s constant has *nothing* to do with relativity and *nothing* to do with electromagnetism.

For example, the Schrodinger equation for a particle in an infinite square well contains $\hbar$ but neither $c$ nor $e$.

Even if the world were quantum-Galilean rather than quantum-Lorentzian, and even if electromagnetism did not exist, quantum mechanics would still require a constant like $\hbar$.

The physical significance of this constant is that it establishes a scale for the physical quantity called [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)). The deepest expression (in my opinion) of the role of $\hbar$ in physics is in Feynman’s [path integral formulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_integral_formulation) of quantum mechanics. It says that all systems evolve in all possible ways, with the probability amplitude for evolving a certain way being proportional to $e^{iS/\hbar}$, where $S$ is the action for that evolution. This is true regardless of whether the system is relativistic or non-relativistic, true regardless of what kinds of forces are operating, and true when *no* forces are operating.

Another example of the deep significance of $\hbar$ is that it establishes the scale of non-commutativity of conjugate observables, as in [canonical commutation relations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_commutation_relation) such as $[\hat x,\hat{p}_x]=i\hbar$. Again, this is independent of both relativity and electromagnetism.

Furthermore, most physicists do not accept that the fine-structure constant is changing. As [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Is_the_fine-structure_constant_actually_constant?) explains, “So far, most experimental data is consistent with α being constant.”

By the way, your equation $E=\hbar\nu$ is off by a factor of $2\pi$. It is either $E=h\nu$ or $E=\hbar\omega$.

Comment: even better, if you really think fine structure constant is constant, then $e^2/\hbar c$ was a direct relationship isn't it?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking. I have no idea what a “direct relationship” is. The fine structure constant is a dimensionless constant formed from dimensional constants.

Comment: It's better to assume fine structure not being a constant during of which it will support your argument more. However, in the case it does, then one could surely replace $\hbar$ with the other factors, such as fine structure itself, to develop the physical theories. Essentially, $\hbar, e,c$ would be constrained factors. Thus, in theory, one could supplement a new principle to replace anyone of them.

Comment: That would just be meaningless algebra. The three constants are *conceptually unrelated* in today’s physics. There is no accepted theory that forces $\alpha$ to have the value it does. If you find such a theory, and convince physicists to accept it, *then* the three dimehsional constants will no longer be conceptually independent.

Comment: What you are arguing for is similar to arguing, as someone recently did here, that $c$ could be replaced by $1/\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}$ in, say, the Lorentz transformations. It could... if you want to completely misunderstand the significance if the Lorentz transformations. They are much more fundamental than electromagnetism and have nothing to do with any force.

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I was saying, could the redundancy imply the existence of another complementary symmetry that could replace, say Lorentz symmetry?

Comment: No, it doesn’t imply that. I’m getting a message to avoid extended discussions in comments, so I’m done.